# Html and css: drop down menu wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop down menu on the top of my page and I am trying to get that to top of the center on my page. It won't go center and now that drop down effect won't work. if you can solve this problem I'll really appreciate that or you can show me an other cool drop down menu which will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>    </TITLE>

<LINK href="to.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</HEAD>

<BODY>
<DIV ID="header">
<div id="nav">
<div id="nav_wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a>
</li>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">dropdown #1</a>

<ul>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #1</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #2</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #3</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">dropdown #2</a>

<ul>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #1</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #2</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #3</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Nav wrapper end -->
</div>


</DIV>

</DIV>

<DIV ID="wrapper">
<DIV ID="content_area">
<p> </p>
<center>
<video width="900" height="550" controls autoplay>
<source src="fifa.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="fifa.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="fifa.webm" type="video/webm">
<object data="fifa.mp4" width="320" height="240">
<embed src="fifa.swf" width="320" height="240">
</object> 
</video>
</center>

</DIV>
</DIV>

<DIV ID="footer">
Hello and Welcome --------------
</DIV>


</BODY>

</HTML>

CSS:

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
min-width:525px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 17px;
background-image:url('fifa2.jpg');
}

#header {
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
backgroundcolor: 

}


#footer {
float: left;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
font-size: 14pt;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
height: 40px;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
padding-left: 200px;
padding-right: 125px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#left_side {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 200px;
right: 200px;
margin-left: -100%;
padding-bottom: 2000px;
margin-bottom: -2000px;
}

#right_side {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 125px;
background-color: #66CCCC;
margin-right: -125px;
padding-bottom: 2000px;
margin-bottom: -2000px;
}

#content_area {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 2000px;
margin-bottom: -2000px;
}


#nav {
background-color: #222;
}
#nav_wrapper {
width: 350px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}
#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
color: #CCC;
display: block;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border: 5px solid #222;
border-top: 0;
margin-left: -5px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
color: #699;
}


video {
margin-top: 250px;
}
```

[image: image:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML formatting is wrong. Change it as below

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2wzns62b/3/)**

```
<div id="header">
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">dropdown #1</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #3</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">dropdown #2</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #3</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav wrapper end -->
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content_area">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
<DIV ID="footer">Hello and Welcome --------------</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use [jQuery UI's Menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/).

Example (took from the page above):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>jQuery UI Menu - Default functionality</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
     <script>
       $(function() {
         $( "#menu" ).menu();
       });
     </script>
     <style>
       .ui-menu { width: 150px; }
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul id="menu">
      <li class="ui-state-disabled">Aberdeen</li>
      <li>Ada</li>
      <li>Adamsville</li>
      <li>Addyston</li>
      <li>Delphi
        <ul>
          <li class="ui-state-disabled">Ada</li>
          <li>Saarland</li>
          <li>Salzburg an der schönen Donau</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Saarland</li>
      <li>Salzburg
        <ul>
          <li>Delphi
            <ul>
              <li>Ada</li>
              <li>Saarland</li>
              <li>Salzburg</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Delphi
            <ul>
              <li>Ada</li>
              <li>Saarland</li>
              <li>Salzburg</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Perch</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-disabled">Amesville</li>
    </ul>


  </body>
</html>
```